# ADO.NET parameterized query is not executed correctly

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, ado.net

I have this parameterized query :

```
SELECT 
   ClientId, FirstName, LastName, AccNumber, AccBalance, Created
FROM 
   (SELECT 
       tbl.*, 
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY @dbColumnOrder ASC) AS rownum 
    FROM [DB].[dbo].[MyTable] AS tbl 
    WHERE @dbColumnFilter IS NOT NULL) seq 
WHERE 
    seq.rownum BETWEEN @iDisplayStart AND @iDisplayLength
```

And I set the parameters like this:

```
command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@dbColumnOrder", columns[iSortCol]));
command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@dbColumnFilter", "AccNumber"));
command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@iDisplayStart", iDisplayStart));
command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@iDisplayLength", (iDisplayLength + iDisplayStart)));
```

I debug it many times so I'm sure that I have the correct values to for the second argument of `new SqlParameter()`. However when I get the result it's as if `WHERE @dbColumnFilter IS NOT NULL` was no executed at all, also I think that `ORDER BY @dbColumnOrder ASC` is also skipped. If I go to `Ms SQL Server Management Studio` and execute the query manually by replacing the parameters with concrete values like so :

```
SELECT 
   ClientId, FirstName, LastName, AccNumber, AccBalance, Created
FROM 
   (SELECT 
       tbl.*, 
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ClientId ASC) AS rownum 
    FROM [DB].[dbo].[MyTable] AS tbl 
    WHERE AccNumber IS NOT NULL) seq  
WHERE 
    seq.rownum BETWEEN 0 AND 10
```

I get the expected result. Also I tried to hardcode the values that I pass to the database like so:

```
command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@dbColumnOrder", "ClientId");
command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@dbColumnFilter", "AccNumber"));
command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@iDisplayStart", 0));
command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@iDisplayLength", 10));
```

But still the result from the database is as if the `OrderBy` and `IS NOT NULL` are not executed.

Comment: As I know, you can't use parameters for column- or tablename. See: [http://stackoverflow.com/a/6376211/2655508](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6376211/2655508)

Comment: You cannot use a parameter for a column-name. You need [dynamic sql](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html).

Comment: Yeap, exactly. That's the correct answer. I can not use parameteres for table/column names.